# React css modules и путь

Tags: css, reactjs

Помогите пожалуйста, мне выдает вот такую ошибку при подключении css modules:

```
 Failed to compile
    ./src/components/sidebar/sidebar.module.css
    Module not found: You attempted to import ../../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
```

Хотя файлы находится в src/components/sidebar.jsx и src/components/sidebar.module.css.

Вот так пытаюсь подключить в sidebar.jsx

```
import classes from './sidebar.module.css';
```

Что мне нужно сделать, чтобы заработал module.css?

Comment: Вы в самом css, что-то еще импортите?

Comment: Нет, там только стили прописаны. Нужно что-то дописать в css?